# Opening the share extension menu on iOS from a website

Tags: javascript, html, ios, iphone, safari

Is it possible to open the share extension menu on iOS from a website?

I want to put a button on my website that when tapped will open the native share extension on iOS

Comment: I dont think its possible if u want to do it with javascript

Comment: can you find solution?